# Show or Hide Prev and next buttons based on first div and last div in angular2

Tags: html, angular

I have a requirement where i want to hide or show prev and next buttons based on div tag. Basically i am creating div tags for each value of list using ngfor loop in angular2.

List I have used

```
appUlist:string[] = ["Calculus-1","Geometry-1","Algebra-1","Trignometry-1","Statstics-1","Arithmetic-1"]
```

Now i am creating a div tag for each value in the list using ngFor in html. Since there are more than 5 values in the list, i have used next and prev button so that i can see other div tags as soon as i click on next button. This part works pretty well. but i want hide prev button if i am showing the first div tag and hide next button if there are no further div tags.

Please advice me on this
Below i have posted both html and ts code

```
    export class AppComponent{
      @ViewChild('panel', { read: ElementRef }) public panel: ElementRef<any>;
     public selectedDiv;
     public u;
      title = 'app';
      name:string = 'Creating new screen for student';

     public appUlist:string[] = ["Calculus-1","Geometry-1","Algebra-1","Trignometry-1","Statstics-1","Arithmetic-1"]
     }
//scrolls back when clicked on prev
    public onPreviousSearchPosition(): void {
      this.panel.nativeElement.scrollLeft -= 20
    }
 //scrolls forward when clicked on next button     
      public onNextSearchPosition(): void {
     this.panel.nativeElement.scrollBy(20,0);
     }
```

My html code

```
         <div #panel class="row" style="width:700px;height:300px;overflow-x: scroll;overflow: hidden;" >
        <div class="col-lg-1">
 <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" style="font-size:36px;color:#1092B0" id="left" (click)="onPreviousSearchPosition()"></i>
</div>  
        <div class="col-lg-1 cardhover" *ngFor="let u of appUlist">
                    <h1>test</h1> 
         </div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" style="font-size:36px;color:#1092B0" id="right" (click)="onNextSearchPosition()"></i>
</div>
    </div>
```

Below image represents the output of mycode
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put a variable to 0 in your appComponent and increment/decrement it each time you click prev and next. If this variable is == 0 you don't show prev button, if it is equal to your list lenght - 3 you don't show the next button :

```
export class AppComponent{
      @ViewChild('panel', { read: ElementRef }) public panel: ElementRef<any>;
     public selectedDiv;
     public u;

     public index = 0;
      title = 'app';
      name:string = 'Creating new screen for student';

     public appUlist:string[] = ["Calculus-1","Geometry-1","Algebra-1","Trignometry-1","Statstics-1","Arithmetic-1"]
     }
//scrolls back when clicked on prev
    public onPreviousSearchPosition(): void {
      this.panel.nativeElement.scrollLeft -= 20
      this.index--;
    }
 //scrolls forward when clicked on next button     
      public onNextSearchPosition(): void {
     this.panel.nativeElement.scrollBy(20,0);
      this.index++;
     }
```

and

```
 <div #panel class="row" style="width:700px;height:300px;overflow-x: scroll;overflow: hidden;" >
        <div class="col-lg-1">
 <i *ngIf="idx != 0" class="fa fa-angle-double-left" style="font-size:36px;color:#1092B0" id="left" (click)="onPreviousSearchPosition()"></i>
</div>  
        <div class="col-lg-1 cardhover" *ngFor="let u of appUlist">
                    <h1>test</h1> 
         </div>
<div class="col-lg-1">
    <i *ngIf="idx < list.lenght - 3" class="fa fa-angle-double-left" style="font-size:36px;color:#1092B0" id="right" (click)="onNextSearchPosition()"></i>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You have mentioned that to check if index equals list length.. But how will index be equals list length  if more than one div is shown each time next button is clicked

Comment: you are right you have to check if index is inferior to the list lenght - 3